# ¿Por qué el renombramiento de columnas no me funciona en mi consulta sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

quiero renombrar la columnas NOMBRE y NUMERO DOC. Dejo el código a continuación:

`SELECT  NOMBRE  AS  nom,NUMERO DOC AS num FROM clientes_Base16`

Comment: Por qué dices que no funciona? Seguro de esos nombres de columna? (sobre todo el que tiene un espacio). Esa es la sintaxis estándar para definir alias en SQLite. Puedes probar también omitiendo el `AS` y simplemente separando con un espacio el nombre de la columna y el alias.

Comment: asi esta en la tabla con esos espacios , lo vi en la opción de browseData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé cómo estás ejecutando la consulta o si estás omitiendo errores.

Si nombraste la columna usando un espacio en `NUMERO DOC`, eso no va a servir. De paso, qué terrible práctica usar espacios. Receta para sufrir barato.

Si de veras necesitas los espacios, debes rodear el nombre del campo. Aquí hay un [ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/18ab52/1) (ya que tampoco mostraste tu tabla en la pregunta)

```
CREATE TABLE clientes_Base16
    (
     NOMBRE integer primary key, 
     `NUMERO DOC` varchar(20), 
     pepito varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO clientes_Base16
VALUES
(1, 'Email', 'admin@sqlfiddle.com');

INSERT INTO clientes_Base16
VALUES
(2, 'Twitter', '@sqlfiddle');
```

La consulta debe usar backticks también

```
SELECT  
NOMBRE  AS  nom, 
`NUMERO DOC` AS num 
FROM clientes_Base16
```